# React hooks -to reinitialise array to empty

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

i do have one state written as

```
const[checkboxIds,setCheckboxIds]=useState([])
```

and i have one useEffect as

```
useEffect(()=>{
    if (!isEmpty(currentData)) {
      currentData.forEach(id => {
        checkboxIds.push(id);
      });
      setCheckboxIds(checkboxIds);
    }
},[currentData])
```

and i am showing the count as {checkboxIds} and is displaying correct

Again i do have 4 tabs like alphabets,colors,animals and cars,when i click on each tab **current Data** changes ,so checkboxIds count also should change. its changing, but its incrementing previous count as well

For example if i do have 10 objects in alphabets, its showing count as 10 in the initial page load and when i click on colors(it have 5 objects),its showing count as 15 (it should show only 5) and when i click on animals(it have 10 object) ,its showing count as 25(it should show its count as 10)

so i understood somwhere setCheckboxIds should be reinitiated ,but for me its not working

Comment: What `checkboxIds.push(id);` suppose to do as `checkboxIds` is state? Where property `selectedCheckboxIds` is initialized. I don't see that.

Comment: some more context please. where do all those variables come from?

Comment: @Sandy its a typo error and i had made it correct

Comment: @bbortt its an array of objects and each object do have id in it. i am just segregating id's to another array

Comment: Ah, I think you're copying the old value of the array then in `useEffect`. You would have to initialize an empty array first, then `push` to this one. That's probably why it increases.

Comment: `checkboxIds` is stateand hence its value is remembered by component. Take a new variable, push new into it and set it. That should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to update your useEffect to

```
useEffect(()=>{
    if (!isEmpty(currentData)) {
      const updatedCheckboxIds = [];
      currentData.forEach(id => {
        updatedCheckboxIds.push(id);
      });
      setCheckboxIds(updatedCheckboxIds);
    }
},[currentData])
```

This way on each effect it will create a new checkboxIds array and will push the ids into it.

Comment: Or `setCheckboxIds([...currentData])`